# Javascript function passing

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problem. I need to pass the hello function to name and them later call it. But I get the error, hello is not a function.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            hello = function(){
                alert("hello! I'm called") ;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            name = function( hello ) {
                hello() ;
            }
            name();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you hide hello function with argument "hello" that is used in the name function definition. when you invoke name(), you don't pass function. call name as name( hello ); also don't hide gloval names like this

Comment: @Alexandr Ops! My mistake. But in this case Firefox working fine and chrome does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining a parameter called `hello` within `name()`, but you are calling `name()` with no parameter, thus `hello` is undefined within the context of `name()`.  Either pass the parameter when you call `name()`, or remove the parameter completely:

```
name = function (hello) {
    hello();
}
name(hello);
```

or

```
name = function() {
    hello();
}
name();
```

Comment: Can't you simply do... 
`function() {
hello();
}`

Comment: @Consciousness Actually I have a complex problem in real, I made it easy here :) Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 5):

Inside `name`, `hello` will refer to the *parameter* `hello`. As you are calling the function without passing any argument, `hello` is `undefined`.

Either pass the function as argument

```
name(hello);
```

or omit the parameter specification, so that `hello` will refer to the global variable:

```
name = function() {
    hello();
};
```

You should avoid having global variables, so that they do not collide with `window` properties or other libraries. You can use an object as namespace:

```
var myNameSpace = {};
myNameSpace.hello = function...
myNameSpace.name = function...
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two problem with your code.

1. You cannot declare a `variable` name that is already existing in the `Window` class.
2. Your name `function` contains a parameter that is named by the `hello` function. For that you need to pass a function delegate in order to achieve this.

Take a look at the complete code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var hello = function(){
                alert("hello! I'm called") ;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var nameFunc = function( helloDelegate ) {
                helloDelegate() ;
            }
            nameFunc(hello);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change it completely to this:

```
function hello(){
    alert("hello! I'm called");
}

function name(hello) {
    hello() ;
}

name(hello);
```

No need to assign the functions to variables like you are doing.

Like others have said, the main problem was that you weren't passing anything into the name function.

Comment: Passing the parameter `hello` is useless in `name` function. No matter what you provide, JS engine will lookup functions first than parameters and evaluate.

Comment: @MunimAbdul Try running that code without passing in the parameter. It doesn't call the hello function.

Answer (score 1):

Dewsworld, just learn how to debug javascript. It'll help you to investigate the problem and find solution yourself. In some browsers debuggers is built-in, in others you have to download it. But it does not matter.

As soon as you start execute your scripts step-by-step, you'll see all its variables current state and it'll be more clear and effective for your than giving reason of the problem you have met.

Also, read JavaScript The Definitive Guide, the last edition. At least try to find solution and reason of this in the book. Cause here you only get short solution, as a rule, without deep undestanding how JavaScript engine works.